# Google Sheets Percentage Formula with multiple variables

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am wondering if someone with Google Sheets expertise can help me figure out how to write a formula to find percentages based on 2 parameters.

For Example, please see screenshot below, we want to figure out what percentage of the cost is included(Y/N) within each fruit (oranges/apples). What would be the best formula to solution for this?

Thank you!

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sumif() will give the total cost, then if() will do the % calculation for any Y.

Comment: Sorry I'm very much a beginner, you lost me on the if(0 portion. Could you please show the formulation?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I would start with a pivot like this =query(A2:C,"select A,sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B") and add formulas to calculate the percentages.

Comment: I agree with player0. Your expected output is not made clear in your post. And there are many details we will need to know in order to suggest a formula, which will be most efficiently shared if you include a link to the sample spreadsheet *with your expected results already entered by hand where you'd like to see them*.